# How can I solve $200 = \frac{ ( \sqrt{w^2+h^2} )}{32}$ where the ratio of w:h is 16:9?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to calculate the pixel size of 32" 16:9 200 PPI display. The only formula I found was $$200 = \frac{ ( \sqrt{w^2+h^2} )}{32}$$ where the ratio of w:h is 16:9.

How do I solve it?  I haven't had to do intensive Calc or even algebra work in years.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $w=16x$ and $h=9x$. The problem gets reduced to that of solving a single-variable equation, which can be solved trivially.